# Is an application-level controller acceptable in Angular when used for constants?

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, architecture

I am creating an application that has a lot of interacting sub-components. Many of the different views display some of the same data in summary format. The data that is retrieved from the REST calls returns codes, and I need to do lookups for those codes. I want to create an application-level controller to hold all the code-translate objects (constants) used everywhere. Would this follow best practices?

Something along the lines of below. So the main body will have the "appCtrl" that houses the constants built off web-services, and then the different includes can reference them as children of the parent controller.

**index.html**

```
 <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="appCtrl" class="container-fluid">    
            <div data-ng-include data-src="'navigation/navigation.html'"></div>
            <div id="mainContent" data-ng-view></div>
            <div id="versionTag">
                APP: v<span data-app-version></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

**navigation.html**

```
<div data-ng-controller="aumNavigationCtrl">
.
.
.
</div>
```

**app.js** *(this is truncated to give you an idea)*

```
    .controller('appCtrl', ['$scope','Tasks',
      function($scope, Tasks)
      {
        //define task types to use in app
        $scope.taskTypes = [];
        Tasks.getTypes({},{}).$promise.then(
          function(data)
          {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
              $scope.taskTypes[i] = 
              { 
                 "code": data[i].code, 
                 "description": data[i].description
              };
            }
          });
    });
```

**navigation.js** *(again, truncated for brevity)*

```
.controller('aumNavigationCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope)
{
    $scope.getTypeDescrip = function(typeCode)
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.taskTypes.length; i++)
      {
        if (typeCode === $scope.taskTypes[i].code)
        {
          $scope.typeDescrip = $scope.taskTypes[i].description;
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Usually, a controller is not designed to do what you are describing. Services are.
See a little fiddler just created for you :)

https://jsfiddle.net/ahjq5tgg/

Comment: Thanks I'll research services more and see what I can find from there, ans I'm pretty unfamiliar with them.

Comment: Do not hesitate to share here what you've found and leaned, I'll be happy to help you if you need!

Comment: I've gone ahead and implemented a service to handle the comparison. I've got an app-level controller to handle all the web-service calls and build the scope objects. It's edited a bit for the unnecessary parts (like the Tasks factory for calling webservices, and some before and after process stuff), but should give you a good idea. And it works, so there's that :D


Here's a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AKarstaedt/0741e7wy/

Comment: I think the following fiddle would also work as expected, but a lot more simplest :) https://jsfiddle.net/c1q36n7v/1/